# jQuery not pushing JSON-data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have the  following script which is supposed to pull data and display it in a HTML table:

```
$('#search_filter_button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop form submission
    var county = $('#filter_county').val(),
        kp_type = $('#filter_kp_type').val(),
        getUrl = window.location,
        baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];

    html_tr = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: baseUrl + "/reports/get_report.php?county=" + county + "&kp_type=" + kp_type,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {    
                html_tr += '<tr>\n\
                <td>' + data[i].name + '</td>\n\
                <td>' + data[i].Abbrv + '</td>\n\\n\
                <td>' + data[i].partner_name + '</td>\n\\n\
                <td>' + data[i].facility_name + '</td>\n\\n\
                <td>' + data[i].county + '</td>\n\\n\
                <td>' + data[i].no_kps + '</td>\n\\n\
                <td>' + data[i].activity_stamp + '</td>\n\</tr>';
            }

            $('#tbody_append').empty();
            $('#tbody_append').append(html_tr);
        }, error: function (data) {
        }
    });
});
```

My get_report.php file looks like this:

```
include '../database/db_connect.php';

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

$county = $_GET['county'];
$kp_type = $_GET['kp_type'];

// get the records from the database
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `no_individaul_kps_contacted` where county='$county'");

$count_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count_row >= 1) {
    // display records if there are records to display

    while ($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo json_encode($user_data);
    }
} else {
    // show an error if there is an issue with the database query
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}

// close database connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

This pulls the information and echoes it back in JSON ENCODE format. But my JavaScript is not returning a success.
Please advise what am I doing wrong.

Comment: any error on console?

Comment: Try `dataType:"text"` and take a look at your server response. It is valid json format? You can validate the response here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Try Alexandr answer and in addition to that just for optimizing purpose you can use $.each(data, function(key, index){....}) and $('#tbody_append').empty().append(html_tr) instead of two separate lines;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the user data into array inside the while loop and move `json_encode($data)` outside the while loop:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM `no_individaul_kps_contacted` where county='$county'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select);
$data = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Seems mostly correct except hat he is using `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`. Could further improve this by appending possible `$mysqli->error` to the `$data`array by doing `$data["error"] = $mysqli->error;` (or pushing it) for the case that an error is thrown and then looking for the error key in the ajax callback. (since he seems to want to echo the error)

Comment: The php side is working well.It is pushing the data but the j query is not receiving the  data.